# Projecting on a 3D plane - and simpifying to 2D?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d, projection

I'm not really a maths guy so I'd appreciate any help on his matter.

I have three points in 3D that define a plane.

I have two vectors, that have their starting points in the 3D plane; in fact these two were used to define the plane.

I project the vectors on the plane so I have two 3D vectors that are in the plane.
From here on the 3D problem could be reduced to a 2D problem and could be used using really basic techniques.

Question is: how do I do the last step - reducing the dimensionality from three to two? As the plane is a general 3D plane, I guess omitting one of the coordinates is not the way to go.

Comment: I assume that you choose one of the points as the origin. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Andrei, thanks for the comment. You are right, but it is just part of the solution. Unfortunately in this case I was at the beginning of thinking about the problem, and by thinking about it a bit more I must confess: the question asked is not the right one.